# Artefacts while filling in faces

Tags: vertices

I'm incredibly new to Blender, so I apologise if this question has a simple answer.

I'm trying to select vertices and fill them in, but when I do the filled faces seem to overlap with another face.

Here's a screenshot of the problem.[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the verts or edges that make up the hole and press the **F** key. Your hole will be filled in as long as all the verts or edges are part of the same mesh.